# Newbie how does c# threading handle events raised on another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Lets say I have 2 threads - thread A and thread B. I register an event on thread A and invoke it from thread B. Which thread would the event be executed on?

Are there any special scenario when the above is not applicable?

Also how to make a class thread safe without using any locks.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Unless you take some explicit action, event handlers are called on the thread that raises the event. Typically "raising an event" is *just* matter of invoking a delegate, which is a synchronous operation on the same thread.

> Also how to make a class thread safe without using any locks.

We don't have *nearly* enough information to answer that, and it would be in a different question ideally. But before asking that separate question, you should really ask yourself what you mean by "thread safe" - it can mean lots of different things to different people. See [Eric Lippert's blog post on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx) for more information.

(In particular if you're thinking about events, consider the possibility that one thread subscribes to or unsubscribes from an event *while it's being raised* - what do you need to happen?)

Comment: Thanks Jon. So for the first part of question - no matter what thread registers the event - the invoking thread is the thread which will handle execution.

Comment: @Alag20: Yes, unless you take steps to do something different. Basically there's nothing automagically provided for you.

Comment: Regarding the second question - it is a general question - what needs to be done to make any class thread safe. This may be with variables , events, subscribers etc.

Comment: amazing answer :) the scenario above would handle threads via critical sections

Comment: @Alag20: Again, you'd need to work out exactly what you mean by that first. In general, making a type immutable is a good start - but you need to read Eric Lippert's blog post so that you know exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @saeed: A critical section *is* a lock, effectively.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks i knew that critical section is more common in VC++

Comment: @[Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), I'm working on my [data manager](https://github.com/MercedeX/GenericDataManager) and I want to implement the similar functionality, The events can be raised from any thread but I want them to be processed at the main thread the one that instantiates the library. I cannot rely on Dispatcher as the library can be used in console app too. What are the alternatives that work in Web, WinForm, WCF, console and Win Service? I've the reference to the threads

Comment: @SimpleFellow: There aren't any - there's no equivalent in console apps, for example. You'll need to write your own. You might want to look at `SynchronizationContext` as an existing data type that is used for Windows Forms, ASP.NET and WPF.